# My if statement isnt working in my Python file

Tags: python

I am trying to code a volume calculator for my math class but this keeps happening:

```
Cylinder, Cone, or Sphere: cone

Enter height:10

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    answer = radius*radius*height*pi
NameError: name 'radius' is not defined
```

Here is my code:

```
import math

volumefinder = input("Cylinder, Cone, or Sphere: ")

if volumefinder == 'Cylinder':
  
radius = int(input("Enter radius:"))

height = int(input("Enter height:"))

pi = math.pi

answer = radius*radius*height*pi

print(answer)


if volumefinder == 'Cone':

  radius = int(input("Enter radius:"))

height = int(input("Enter height:"))

pi = math.pi

answer = 1/3*radius*radius*height*pi

print(answer)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please `format the code` and make sure the indentation is correct. BTW, the input `cone` is invalid because the code expects either `Sphere` or `Cone`, _with a capital `C`_

Comment: If you input anything other than `Cylinder` or `Cone`, you never set a value for `radius`.

Comment: Also `cone` is not the same string as `Cone`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problems are with indents, I suppose you wanted to do something like

```
import math
answer = "Wrong choice"

volumefinder = input("Cylinder, Cone, or Sphere: ")

if volumefinder == 'Cylinder':
    radius = int(input("Enter radius:"))
    height = int(input("Enter height:"))
    pi = math.pi
    answer = radius*radius*height*pi

if volumefinder == 'Cone':
    radius = int(input("Enter radius:"))
    height = int(input("Enter height:"))
    pi = math.pi
    answer = 1/3*radius*radius*height*pi

print(answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

before exact program: I am not sure it is the exact code you have written, this form looks incorrect indentation and 2 different radius variables. If this is the exact code then these are the error else It will be helpful if you post your exact code.

After the exact program: you have mentioned "Cone" in program but you are calling with "cone" in the terminal, indentation is still the issue here.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Indentation isn't correct -_-

```
import math

volumefinder = input("Cylinder, Cone, or Sphere: ")
if volumefinder == 'Cylinder':
    radius = int(input("Enter radius:"))
    height = int(input("Enter height:"))
    pi = math.pi
    answer = radius*radius*height*pi
    print(answer)

if volumefinder == 'Cone':
    radius = int(input("Enter radius:"))
    height = int(input("Enter height:"))
    pi = math.pi
    answer = 1/3*radius*radius*height*pi
    print(answer)
```